# timeout error on wamp after increasing limits

Tags: php, wamp

I have win10 and  wamp64 , phpmyadmin 4.6.4 , apache 2.4 and i cant import database of 70mb without getting a timeout error after about 5mins.
 I looked online to change settings in the php.ini which didnt resolve the issue so I then changed the config.inc file.

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0; in config.inc file from wamp64/apps/phpmyadmin folder
```

I also change php.ini to these settings
i cant import a database of 72mb and I often import databases of about 50mb without issue.

```
post_max_size = 720M
upload_max_filesize = 720M
max_execution_time = 1200
max_input_time = 1000
memory_limit = 1500M

Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit the same file and import will resume.
```

This is not a duplicate post because if php.ini should not be overwritten by other files or thats what it says. I am happy to try it

Comment: Maybe you should increase the`max_allowed_packet` of mysql too.